# Errno 13 Permission denied '/usr/local/airflow/webserver_config.py' while running airflow on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I have an issue while trying to run Airflow 2.5.0 on Kubernetes.

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow import settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 37, in <module>
    from airflow.configuration import AIRFLOW_HOME, WEBSERVER_CONFIG, conf  # NOQA F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1732, in <module>
    conf = initialize_config()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 1487, in initialize_config
    shutil.copy(_default_config_file_path("default_webserver_config.py"), WEBSERVER_CONFIG)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 427, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/shutil.py", line 266, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/webserver_config.py'
```

I tried to follow multiple approaches available on stackoverflow, like passing load_examples to False, and resetting the database but I am not able to get rid of it.

Airflow user has the following access to this file.

```bash
-rw-r--r--  1 airflow airflow  4744 Mar 20 13:52 webserver_config.py
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Could you share the procedure you performed?
Are you using a particular Helm Chart? Take a look here --> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/parameters-ref.html ; seems well done and well documented how to add webserver_config.py file.

Comment: I hope the shared information was helpful to you in overcoming the issue. If you have any further queries, I am happy to offer further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html):

> On Linux, the quick-start needs to know your host user id and needs to
> have a group id set to 0. Otherwise the files created in dags, logs
> and plugins will be created with root user ownership. You have to make
> sure to configure them for the docker-compose:

```
mkdir -p ./dags ./logs ./plugins

echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env
```

Once you have matched file permissions:

```
docker compose up airflow-init
```

Folder permission that is bind mounted could also result in this error.

For example:

```
docker-compose.yml (pseudo code)
service_name: ... volumes: - 
/home/user/airflow_logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

Grant permission to the local folder, so that the airflow container can write logs, create a directory if needed etc.

```
sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx /home/user/airflow_logs
```